# Query regarding docker, test environments and dev workflow

Tags: testing, docker

I am a QA automation engineer and I am investigating docker as a potential way to run our tests.

Traditionally we have followed the git flow method where essentially where you have a dev and a master branch. Dev are constantly merging their new changes to the dev branch. When we wish to release, we will have a code cut off, where everything currently on the dev branch is deemed to be part of the next release. Script is then run to create the release candidate and this is deployed to staging. Any fixes that need to be done are made to the release branch and once ready to go to prod, new code is merged to master and deployed. Master is back merged to all branches so that everything is up to date. (described in more detail here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

So my question is with docker do you need to have this workflow? Im thinking of maybe having a workflow like describe below:

- Dev start working on a new feature.
- Dev pulls master, creates feature branch - does his dev work - unit tests pass, dev is happy for work to go to QA
- Dev runs script to create release candidate (which would involve pulling master again in case new code has been merged to master by another dev),
- Docker then spins up a container with multiple containers inside that (front end app, DB instance etc)
- Tests (unit, api, selenium integration etc) are then run against this release candidate and if good deploy to production.

So do I need a staging env in the traditional sense where it is constantly available?

Comment: do you mean that you want to replace the staging environment by the developper's computer (running docker containers)?

Comment: Hi Thomasleveil - In a way I guess. The staging environment would just be created when the dev runs the script to create the release candidate. I mean using docker means we should be able to spin up containers that match production very quickly so do we need a staging env in a traditional sense? Sorry if this is not very clear, just trying to get my head around Docker now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're conflating two things: a continuous integration environment and a staging environment. Docker does make it easy to bring up a fresh instance of your entire stack for continuous integration (see [drone](https://github.com/drone/drone) for a good example), but generally you still need a staging environment that is always available to test against before deploying to prod. This staging environment should be running the same docker images that eventually get deployed to prod.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Abdullah. You were correct. After more thought staging env stays!